# Cancel execution of method after it starts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider this method:

```
Future<void> methodWithAlotOfSteps()async{
  callMethodA();
  await callMethodB();
  ...
  return ...;
}
```

which makes some computation. Suppose I want the user to be able to stop this process at any point in time (when he taps `cancel` button for example).

How can I stop the execution of the above method no matter what line in the method the "program counter" has reached when the user presses `cancel`.

I am looking for something like `methodWithAlotOfSteps.cancel();`.

I tried using `CancelableCompleter`, but even though the `Future` is cancelled and `onCancel` method of the completer is called, but the function continues execution.

I know I can set a boolean flag and check it after each "step" ("line", "call to a method"),such as :

```
Future<void> methodWithAlotOfSteps()async{
  if(!completer.isCancelled)
  callMethodA();
  if(!completer.isCancelled)
  await callMethodB();
  ...
  return ...;
}
```

but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can work with StreamSubscription https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510420/is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-function-call-after-it-has-been-called/73510505#73510505

Comment: @OzanTaskiran can you please explain more how can I stop the execution of the method in the way you are suggesting?

Comment: I'm not aware of any better way to do it.  However, you usually would need to check only after each `await`, not after every line.

Comment: @jamesdlin my method does some heavy work (with images and loops), so I need to stop the execution as soon as possible if the user cancels so that no unwanted side effects (like file writes) will be done, so right now I am forced to do the check on the completer at each line that has such side effect

Comment: @Haidar The user will only be able to cancel when your code returns to the event loop, which will occur when your code reaches an `await`.  Synchronous code generally is not interruptible by user events, so there's no point in checking after each line.

Comment: @jamesdlin I get you, thx for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jamesdlin suggested, the apparent way is to check the cancelable completer's state after each async gap:

```dart
class MyService{
  CancelableCompleter completer = CancelableCompleter();
  
  Future<void> doSomething() async {
    doSomeSyncWork(); // Sync work
    doAnotherSyncWork(); // Sync work
    await doSomeAsyncWork(); // Async work, this will return control to event loop and make it possible to, for example, press a button to cancel the future.
    // here we know we have lost control for a while, so we must check if we have been cancelled
    if (completer.isCompleted) {
      return;
    }
    doSomeMoreSyncWork();
    await doSomeMoreAsyncWork();
    // here we know we have lost control for a while, so we must check if we have been cancelled
    if (completer.isCompleted) {
      return;
    }
    ...
    completer.complete();
  }
}
```